# why merge is slow in oracle while the using query is fast and destination table is small in Oracle

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I wrote a merge into Query. this query is very slow. but when i run using query the result is interesting.
the query inside using part is fast and is a group by query and runs in 2 min(max time) with 200 records as result.
The destination table is small and have 20K records.

Nevertheless the whole merge query is slow and takes 100 minutes.
the plan of query is based on hash join.

can you help me about finding the problem of this merge query.
my database is oracle 11g

Comment: Please reread your question and try to find any **facts** that **may** provide any possible reasons of such performance. And then update the question with a query plan and a query text. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info

Comment: Not even a query plan will tell us what we need to know. Every query plan that Oracle cooks up is a "good" plan in some scenario. What matters is the intersection of the plan and the data volume and actual cardinality of rows emitted from each step in the plan, which ultimately drives time spent on each plan step, and that's what we care about. That data can be obtained from v$active_session_history and v$sql_plan_monitor, but is challenging to coach folks into how to grab it properly.

Comment: An Active (format) SQL Monitor report is the best place to start.